# MVC - Add image using varaible paths from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have a 'Details' view and I need it to show the right image for each page. I have used this to display the name etc.

```
<dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(l => l.Name)</dt>
<dd>@Html.DisplayFor(l => l.Name)</dd>
<dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(l => l.Colour)</dt>
<dd>@Html.DisplayFor(l => l.Colour)</dd>
<dt>@Html.DisplayNameFor(l => l.Level)</dt>
<dd>@Html.DisplayFor(l => l.Level)</dd>
```

The same method doesn't work with an image though.

```
@Url.Content(Html.DisplayFor(l => l.ImageURL))
```

That says that it can't convert an MvcHtmlString to a string and

```
@Url.Content(l => l.ImageURL)
```

says that it can't convert the lambda expression to a string because it is 'not a delegate type'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Url.Content()` is simply expecting a string.  Not HTML elements, not expressions or functions, simply the string for the path of the content.  All you need to do is pass it that string from your model:

```
@Url.Content(Model.ImageURL)
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.